# Arc length vs Surface of revolution.

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals, applications

I don't understand why these two problems are solved differently here the first one $fig(1)$ and 2nd one $fig(2)$. Why did we take the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{r\to0^+}\int_r^\pi \sqrt{2-2cost}\space dt$ in the arc length problem but not in the Surface are problem, Although the cycloid is not differentiable at $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$

[image]

$fig(1)$

[image]

$fig(2)$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> The images are small and a little blurry, but taking a limit as $r \to 0^+$ in the arc length integral was unnecessary because the arc length element is computed from a parametrization. <> Re: _...the cycloid is not differentiable..._: The given parametrization is smooth everywhere, and can be used to calculate arc length and surface area. It's true that the cycloid has a vertical tangent where it touches the axis. That necessitates an improper integral if we use the arc length formula for a graph $y = f(x)$.

Comment: Can you get higher resolution images than that? Anyway, your question is why $\int_0^\pi\sqrt{1-\cos t}\mathrm{d}t$ needed more care than $\int_0^\pi(3-2\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2})|\sin\frac{\theta}{2}|\mathrm{d}\theta$, with the former changed to $\lim_{r\to0^+}\int_r^\pi\sqrt{1-\cos t}\mathrm{d}t$. I don't think it did, since an integrand doesn't have to be differentiable at $0$ to be integrable on $[0,\,\pi]$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang So we only care about the smoothness of what's inside the integral, right?

Comment: Essentially "yes": For a proper integral it's sufficient that the integrand be continuous. We'd only need to take a limit as $r \to 0^+$ if the integrand were unbounded in every neighborhood of $0$, e.g., $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$.